# iFrame re-directs to an error page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, asp-classic

I have a form that posts to an `iFrame` for processing. The iFrame then posts a form forwards in the parent window to a confirmation.

I have added a session variable in the confirmation to indicate that the process is finished.

If the user clicks the back button the form in the iFrame redirects to an error page, but obviously that displays in the iFrame itself.

How can I make the error page trigger in the parent?

```
If Session("Complete") = 1 Then
     Response.Redirect("default.asp?Re-Entry")
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a Response.Redirect, you should use the following:

```
Response.Write( "<script language='Javascript'>" + _
                "window.parent.document.location.href = " + _
                "'default.asp?Re-Entry';" + _
                "</script>")
```

It will send back to the iFrame a portion of JavaScript that will instruct it's parent (the main page) to navigate to the error page.

Here is the complete code of my tests:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %>
<%
    If Request("op") = "process" Then
        If Session("Processed") = 1 Then
            Response.Write( "<script>" + _
                            "window.parent.document.location.href = " + _
                            "'error.asp?msg=AlreadyProcessed';" + _
                            "</script>")
        Else
            Session("Processed") = 1
            Response.Write( "<script>" + 
                            "alert('Hello, " + Request("name") + "!');" + _
                            "</script>")
        End If
        Response.End
    End If
%>
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe name="parallel" id="parallel" width="100%" height="50" />

        <form method="POST" target="parallel" action="iFrame.asp">
            <input type="hidden" name="op" value="process" />
            <b>Your Name</b><br/>
            <input type="text" name="name" width="250" /><br/>
            <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: There was any JS error thrown by the page, or it simply did nothing? Which browser are you using?

Comment: It continues to re-post the form instead of redirecting. Using Chrome

Comment: Why response.write all that script? why not just `%><script>parent.location='default.asp?Re-Entry'</script><%`

Comment: Just a matter of style. The effect is almost teh same, and is more readable. In fact, "all that script" is included in your version.

The "window.parent.document.location" is used instead of shortened forms just for made it clear the DOM path.

The idea here is only to be didactic. There is thousand of other ways to do the same thing. And i'm not in the merit os suggesting XHR instead of Darren's approach.

Comment: I was referring to all those quotes and + and _ instead of having the script block outside the asp code. I personally find that more readable. Also I doubt you need to escape the script tags like you need when you document.write them

Comment: In fact, the escaping is unnecessary... As long as i recall, since i don't code with Classic ASP as my main server technology since 2005, it was necessary for some reason.

The + and _ was just to fit in the StackOverflow page, i did it all in one line each script.

I personally don't like to put content closing the ASP tag and reopening it. But i'ts just my opinion, some share it, some discord.

Anyway, thanks for your thoughts! And sorry about my poor english!

Answer (score -1):

i THINK the code u r using is wrong according to me if u use the below code that may help u

```
Response.Write("<scr" + "ipt language='Javascript'>" + _
               "document.parent.navigate('default.asp?Re-Entry');" + _
               "</scr" + "ipt>")
```

Comment: document.navigate is not very compatible. Use parent.location=".." instead